# Cordova "failed to fetch plugin" error

Tags: cordova

I've run into this "Failed to fetch plugin error" quite frequently lately. It seems especially easy to prop up if I download my own branch:

> t2wu@THW-air:~/Documents/Work/John/DEMO_APP/BCAppII(dev) $ cordova
>   plugin add https://github.com/t2wu/cordova-plugin-geofence.git#t2wu
>
> Error: Failed to fetch plugin
>   https://github.com/t2wu/cordova-plugin-geofence.git#t2wu via registry.
>   Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is
>   incorrect. Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL. Failed
>   to get absolute path to installed module

If I download a plugin like `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geofence`, but when I have to use a specific repo, especially a branch on that repo, it fails frequently.

I am using Cordova 7.1.0. (Cordova 8 have other issues I'm not willing to touch right now.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try the following:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/t2wu/cordova-plugin-geofence.git#t2wu --nofetch
```

If it doesn't work. Do the following step:

1. Remove all platform (`cordova platform rm android`) and (`cordova platform rm ios`)
2. Remove all plugins `cordova plugin rm plugin-name`.
3. If step2 failed, then delete all plugins using a file manager from directory `<projectroot>/plugins`
4. Add all plugins
5. Add https://github.com/t2wu/cordova-plugin-geofence.git#t2wu
6. Add all platform.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who faced this problem,
it turns out cordova is trying to fetch via registry every time when repo name do not match with plugin id.
I was able to install plugins from private bitbucket just changing the repo name

Comment: WHERE is this repo name that you changed?

Comment: Facing the same error with private repo... so, how to solve it? What names should be changed and where?

Comment: It's the package.json file, the section called "cordova" with the property "id", that should match the id in plugin.xml. Please make SURE that you also clear your cordova cache when building, such as on meteor.  Agreed, this is a solution.

Comment: Thank you both Barry and Vladimir, I spent hours trying to figure out why the cordova-fetch was properly loading all the modules and then doing a second pass with a weird path just on that module. Turns out, the id field in plugin.xml was wrong AND didn't match the repo name either.

Answer (score 0):

In **Cordova 10 and Xcode 13** the solution was to edit `<App>/plugins/fetch.json`
and makes sure the id match with plugin name.

```
"cordova-labs-local-webserver": {
"source": {
  "type": "registry",
  "id": "git+https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugins.git#local-webserver"
}
```

Update id with plugin name

```
"cordova-labs-local-webserver": {
"source": {
  "type": "registry",
  "id": "cordova-labs-local-webserver"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw this issue when I was running `npm install` before doing my `platform add` commands. For some reason this screwed everything up, but if I just dropped `npm install` it was still done as part of the `platform add` commands.

Answer (score 0):

Incase someone is still facing the issue.
I still haven't figured out the root cause for this. But here is a workaround that worked for me.

I downloaded the plugin source code from the repo  unzipped and added to the plugins folder with proper name (remove master and the end of the folder)

Now run your cordova add(Just to add the plugin to package.json  file)

Also i find this answer helpful - [Ionic - Failed to fetch plugin via registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62192348/ionic-failed-to-fetch-plugin-via-registry)