# Ionic - Failed to fetch plugin via registry

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, plugins, ionic4

I want to add an alarm to my application.

I have tried to install `cordova plugin add https://github.com/wnyc/cordova-plugin-wakeuptimer.git` in to my project.

When I run command I get:

> Failed to fetch plugin
>   https://github.com/wnyc/cordova-plugin-wakeuptimer.git via registry.
>   Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.

[image]

Ionic Info:

**Ionic:**

Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.16
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.1.1
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.901.7
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 9.1.7
   @angular/cli                  : 9.1.7
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.2.0

**Cordova:**

Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0, ios 5.1.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 4 other plugins)

**Utility:**

cordova-res : 0.9.0
   native-run  : 0.3.0

**System:**

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
   NodeJS            : v12.14.1
   npm               : 6.13.4
   OS                : Windows 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error is solved by following the below steps :

**1. Download repository source code**
If the plugin is hosted on Github, you can clone it into a local folder on your computer using git e.g (in this example will be cloned into C:/Users/Me/Desktop):

```
git clone https://github.com/wnyc/cordova-plugin-wakeuptimer.git
```

In the clone directory, it should be now (once finished) a new folder with the name of the cloned repository.

**2. Create the package.json file**
To create a new package file for the plugin, you will obviously use Node.js in the command line and execute the following command (once located with the terminal in the folder of plugin):

```
npm init
```

This command will start an interactive prompt (that you can simply skip by pressing Enter on every question) that will allow you to create your package.json file. Obviously, although isn't necessary, you should provide correctly all the information

**3. Install it from the local source**
As the final step, you can install the plugin from the cloned repository but instead of providing the git URL, provide the local path to the plugin:

```
cd FolderOfYourCordovaProject //Where you want to add a plugin

cordova plugin add F:\WorkSpace\cordova-plugin-wakeuptimer
```

When I am adding plugin in my project It throws an error

> Invalid Plugin! C:\Users\Me needs a valid package.json

Then I copied that plugin into the same disk/ same folder where the project is located.
Then this error is also solved. And plugin added successfully.

Comment: This is a workaround but did you ever find the root cause of the problem? In my case the error started happening unexpectedly without any change to my installation steps.

Comment: Did it ever stop happening @UcheOzoemena? It just started for me for no apparent reason...

Comment: @TonaldDrump yeah it ended up being a problem with a dependency of the affected plugin. When you don't change anything and this happens then it often means a dependency has a problem. If you can't find the issue immediately it may be worth leaving it for a few days to see what new reports come up about it.