# Failing to Install Cordova Video Player Plugin

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, npm-install

I am making a Cordova video player on an ionic app. I have tried to install Cordova video player using

```
ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/moust/cordova-plugin-videoplayer.git
npm install @ionic-native/video-player
```

But am getting this error:
Failed to fetch plugin https://github.com/moust/cordova-plugin-videoplayer.git via registry.
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdG02.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Ionic, but when I try your commands without ionic (i.e.:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/moust/cordova-plugin-videoplayer.git
npm install @ionic-native/video-player
```

) It works for me. Maybe you could try the solution suggested in the accepted answer here: [Cordova "failed to fetch plugin" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48293822/cordova-failed-to-fetch-plugin-error)
does that work?